Why to use passive voice in this definition

burn alive
: 1.to kill by being set on fire
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burn%20alive

I want to ask why this sentence uses the passive voice? Is the agent of "to kill" the same as the one in "being set on fire"?
I think the following two expressions should be used:
2. To kill by setting on fire.
3. To be killed by being set on fire.
May I ask where my understanding is incorrect?

I agree with you. I think M-W slipped up there.


burn alive


: to kill by being set on fire
The captives were burned alive.

The dictionary has used burn as an ergative verb in its definition.  Its captive example is in the passive, another valid form.
Its other examples demonstrate the use of the ergative verb:

Two friends burn alive in defective tanning beds


The mentally ill men left to burn alive ...


... who crashed his minivan into a tree while evacuating, only to burn alive with two pets ...

The OP’s interpretations


To kill by setting on fire
3. To be killed by being set on fire


are fine too.  This is the normal transitive verb usage similar to that in M+W's captive example.
